# Oracle 10g: Querying the DATA_DEFAULT column from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view takes a long time

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Try executing this SQL:

```
select OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,
       DATA_LENGTH,DATA_PRECISION,DATA_SCALE,NULLABLE
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'USER';
```

You will need to modify your OWNER string in the where clause. After executing, you'll probably notice that it didn't take very long to run.  Now add the DATA_DEFAULT column like this:

```
select OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH,
       DATA_PRECISION,DATA_SCALE,NULLABLE,DATA_DEFAULT
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'USER';
```

That takes forever.  What's up with the DATA_DEFAULT column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find that happens on my 11.2 database, but I would imagine the reason it can be slow is that DATA_DEFAULT is a LONG column.  Just a guess though.

Comment: My tests are leading to this assumption, as well.  I just got around to playing with this by creating a table with 288 records.  It had a VARCHAR2(10) and a LONG.  When I did my select to return just the VARCHAR2, it took 0.140 seconds.  When I included the LONG column in the select, however, it took 8.737 seconds to return the 288 records.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any significant differences in the explain plan with and without the column?  (You may need some additional privileges to run an explain plan on this view.)  Is the estimated number of rows within about an order of magnitude of the actual number of rows?

The data dictionary objects need good statistics like all other objects, but people tend to forget about them.

Run a query like this to see when the statistics were last gathered.  The query includes some, but not all, of the tables used by ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.  If LAST_ANALYZED is null or very old, that's a bad sign:

```
select last_analyzed, dba_tables.*
from dba_tables
where table_name in ('OBJ$', 'USER$', 'TAB$', 'COL$');
```

Also, as Tony Andrews pointed out, LONGs can cause some problems.  But the DATA_DEFAULT is one of those LONGs that is almost always very tiny, or null.  That makes me
think that it may be a problem with your client instead of the server.  Try running the query with different tools, e.g. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, etc.

Comment: I am using Benthic Golden32, but it also runs slow when I execute the query in C# with an OracleCommand and OracleDataReader object.  It's not a show stopper or anything, but I'd definitely like to know why it's so slow.